# is compare id but id should be the same between -5 and 256, how come it's not if x = 3 and y = 5?

Tags: python, identity-operator

```
a = 10 # range -5 to 256
b = 10 # range -5 to 256
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
print(a is b)

# OK THAT'S FINE
```

BUT

```
a = 10 # range -5 to 256
b = 10 # range -5 to 256
print(id(a))
print(id(b)) # same memory adress
print(a is b)

# That's working

c = 3 # range -5 to 256
d = 5 # range -5 to 256
print(id(c))
print(id(d)) 
print(c is d)
```

NOT same memory adress O_o
False because... meeeehhh the range should be fine !

Comment: You misunderstood the documentation. I don't think it states that all integers from -5 to 256 have the same id.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you saying that you think `3 is 5` should return `True`?

Comment: Of course they cannot be the same id, these are different objects.

Comment: It's somehow obvious that never two different things can have the same id or otherwise, how could one address them independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following illustration, you should understand why:

- `a is b` is True
- `c is d` is False

for the number between -5 and 256

and why:

- `e is f` is False

for other numbers outside of this special range

[image]

Comment: documentation i follow : 
PyObject *PyLong_FromLong(long v)
Return value: New reference. Part of the Stable ABI.
Return a new PyLongObject object from v, or NULL on failure.
https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html?highlight=pylongobject#c.PyLongObject



Corralien, according to your help, this compare the value. but is should compare the id no? 

unless between -5 and 256 the id will be the same only if the value is the same and after the id will be different whatever the result ? will try...

Comment: Ok i think i understand, you were right Corralien !